# apply a procedure to some rows in a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I have a dataframe. I would like to apply a function to selected rows. The final idea could be choose the rows according to some parallelization schemes.

Let's say that a I have a dataframe called "dfr". I have also define a function as:

```
def test(xx):
    
    print(xx)
    
    return
```

I would like to apply test to each row of my dataframe, I could for example use:

```
dfr.apply(test, axis=1)
```

however, how can I do it for all the rows between the 5th row and 15th row?

I have tried "lambda" but it seems not working.

Thanks for any kind of help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC:

```
dfr.iloc[5:15].apply(test, axis = 1)
```

[`pandas.DataFrame.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) let you select rows (and columns) by their positions.

Answer (score 0):

You can make filtered copy of your dataframe that has only certain rows, then run apply or lambda on that filtered copy.  Then merge on the original index to get the output.  You'll want to decide what to do with the null values for the rows you did not do anything to -- maybe overwrite the original column?  Note that apply and lambda are slow, so if you can avoid it, you'll be better off.  Filtering the df reduces the amount of work lambda needs to do.

```
def test(xx):
    return xx + 1

df = pd.DataFrame({'values':[i for i in range(20)]})

df_filtered = df.iloc[6:15, :]  
# For slicing rows explicitly, from 6 up to but not including 15

df_filtered = df_filtered.apply(test, axis=1)

df_filtered = df_filtered.rename(columns={'values':'new_values'})
df = df.join(df_filtered)       # joins on original index
```